# Adding fragments to activity having listview

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I extend fragmentactivity in a class already extending listactivity.
As per my requirement I want tabs in the top of the activity screen and listview in the same activity at the same time.

Comment: in Java you cannot have multiple inheritances.

Comment: Extend fragment activity, then add listview instead of extending it.

Comment: you can't extend two classes in java. In fact you should extent `FragmentActivity` only and use ViewPager. In the fragments which will be loaded you can have listviews.

Comment: I know that one cannot have multiple inheritance in java and thus I had posted the same.

Comment: Anyways thanks for the alternatives will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this library for tabs. https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip.

" How can I extend fragmentactivity in a class already extending listactivity. "
I didn't quite understand the statement. but you can implement multiple fragments in `PagerSlidingTabStrip`. You can show multiple fragments on each `ViewPager` and implement listviews in those fragments.

Comment: I've an activity extending ListActivity. But, now I need to include tabs in my application too for the same activity and thus will require to extend fragmentactivity. But that is not possible in java. So I'm looking for a way around.

Comment: Simple as that. In activity implmement Tabs as I told earlier and each tab can show fragments and each fragment can have listviews. Try some code. and ask if nedd help futher

Comment: Thanks. In fact let me open up a little bit. I'm developing a file explorer app and need to have something like breadcrums in the action bar which change dynamically based on directory navigation and also provide click facility for quick navigation just like tabs.

Comment: You can always extend an advice if you have any alternative to achieve the same

Comment: I am not aware of that method used by E.S. file manager but you can always use spinner in the actionbar to support like breadcrums.

Comment: anytime. happy coding.